# How to catch an LTPA WebSphere exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, security, ltpa

When using LTPA basic authentication with WebSphere 7 if a password is incorrect an exception is thrown thus:

```
[11/24/10 14:51:44:405 CET] 00000011 exception     W com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.file.was.FileAdapter login 
                             com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.PasswordCheckFailedException: CWWIM4512E The password match failed.
```

at com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.file.was.FileAdapter.login(FileAdapter.java:2009)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.loginImpl(ProfileManager.java:3338)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.genericProfileManagerMethod(ProfileManager.java:270)
 at com.ibm.ws.wim.ProfileManager.login(ProfileManager.java:374)

This is with basic authentication enabled in my deployment descriptor (web.xml) not form based.
**The question:**  Is there a way to catch this exception?  This is thrown before the request reaches my servlets.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I can catch it by specifying a 401 error page in web.xml which is fine when making a request not through a browser but if I do this for browser reqeusts then the login prompt is not shown.  Maybe this is not possible with BASIC authentication.

Comment: Also this only shows me an error that there is a problem with the BASIC realm not that the password is incorrect and the exception is still logged in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you insisted on catching that situation you should develop either custom [Trust Association Interceptor](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_waci.html) that would have to handle the basic authentication including the error handling or [custom JAAS login module](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_jaascustlogmod.html).